# How to insert to clickhouse asynchronously with callback function in golang?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, clickhouse, pulsar

Now I want to insert some data from kafka to clickhouse. Is there any way to sense failure after asynchronous insertion failure because of ack?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean by "ack" -- In any case ClickHouse doesn't provide an asynchronous mechanism for acknowledgements.  All acknowledgements are synchronous.  For "async_inserts" you can wait for this acknowledgement by setting `wait_for_async_insert` true.

Comment: I mean confirm the id of message from Kafka.

Comment: This is still too vague.  Do you mean the Kafka key?  You can add a column named `_key` to your Kafka engine table that can be inserted into the associated materialized view.